# Number of elements in $GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> I want to find the number of elements in $GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$, where $p$ is a prime.

The first row can be chosen in $p^2-1$ ways as we can not take both zeros. The second row must be chosen in such a way that it is not a linear combination of the first. Total number of rows those are linear combinations of the first row is $p$. Thus total possibilities for the second row is $p^2-p$. Thus $|GL_2(\mathbb Z_p)|=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$. Am I right?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the field with $p$ elements or the $p$-adic integers? If it's the first (what seems to be the case) this is correct.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: That is correct. A similar argument shows that $|GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)| = (p^n-1)(p^n-p)\cdots(p^n-p^{n-1}).$